# How can I keep a table together in a FlowDocument?

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I thought if I place the Table in a Paragraph that I could use the KeepTogether attribute to keep the table together. The table is used for the totals of a report and the client does not want them broken over two pages. Imagine that! There are 5 rows in the table and I am going crazy not knowing what to try next.

Last line of code:

```
myFlowDocument.Blocks.Add(footerParagraph);
```

The output of footerParagraph begins with:

```
<Paragraph KeepTogether="True">
    <Floater HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Table CellSpacing="0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF000000">
```

KeepTogether ordinarily works, but why not when it contains a Floater and Table? Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue, have you tried using a Figure instead of a Floater. For mine I needed to set the Figure's CanDelayPlacement to false.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the fast and accurate answer! This is exactly what I needed and you increased my FlowDocument vocabulary just enough to get me past this hurdle. Thank you for telling me about figure, and I did not need to use the CanDelayPlacement setting, btw.

Comment: Why has this answer so little upvotes? Is there an other way?