# Keep Table together in flowdocument

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument, paragraph

I am using FlowDocument to print my output.
I have table that show output in four rows.when it comes to end of page table breaks into two pages,like this [image]i want to show table in single page
i have googled and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397089/how-can-i-keep-a-table-together-in-a-flowdocument) ,but i don't know how to add table to paragraph programatically.I have tried by following way,but doesnt work.

```
 Section s = new Section();
            s.BreakPageBefore = true;
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            Bold Heading = new Bold();
            Heading.Inlines.Add("Some sort of heading");
            para.Inlines.Add(Heading);
            LineBreak lb = new LineBreak();
            para.Inlines.Add(lb);
            s.Blocks.Add(para);
            s.Blocks.Add(table);
```

UPDATE:

```
 Figure fg = new Figure(table);

            Paragraph paraa = new Paragraph();
            paraa.KeepTogether = true;
            paraa.Inlines.Add(fg);
            doc.Blocks.Add(paraa);
```

now table is shifted to next page, but it is aligned to right side.How i can make it left aligned?

Comment: from the link you need a `Figure`. The `Figure` has a `Blocks` which can contain Blocks (such as `Table`, ...). Then you add `Figure` to `Paragraph.Inlines`.

Comment: Thanks bro,it's shifting now to next page,but table is aligned to right side now,any idea on how to make it left aligned?

Comment: To align a paragraph you can do this: `TextRange range = new TextRange(yourParagraph.ContentStart, yourParagraph.ContentEnd);    range.ApplyPropertyValue(Block.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Left);`